# Не находится нужный шаблон в теме

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть тема DFD Native для wordpress, там есть тип страниц - портфолио.
Если создать страницу с таким урл - `http://sitename.com/portfolio` 
то при открытии этой страницы во фронтенде, подгружается архивный шаблон для портфолио, а нужно чтобы подгружался специальный шаблон для портфолио.
Этот шаблон выбирается при создании страницы сбоку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если создать страницу портфолио с таким урл - `http://sitename.com/portfolio1` , то загружается правильный шаблон для портфолио.
В чём может быть проблема?

файл **index.php** в корне темы

```
<?php if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit; }

get_header();

get_template_part('inc/loop/components/layout');

if(class_exists('Dfd_Layout_Builder')) {
    new Dfd_Layout_Builder(array(
        'loop' => 'loop',
        'page' => 'post',
        'class' => 'dfd-blog-loop'
    )); 
}

get_footer();
```

файл **archive.php** в корне темы

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit; }

$post_type = get_post_type();
if($post_type == 'portfolio') {
    get_template_part('taxonomy-portfolio');
} elseif($post_type == 'gallery') {
    get_template_part('taxonomy-gallery');
} else {
    get_template_part('index');
}
```

файл **taxonomy-portfolio.php** в корне темы

```
get_header();

get_template_part('inc/loop/components/layout');

if(class_exists('Dfd_Layout_Builder')) {
    new Dfd_Layout_Builder(array(
        'loop' => 'loop',
        'page' => 'portfolio_archive',
        'class' => 'dfd-portfolio-loop'
    ));
}

get_footer();
```

тут убирал `_archive` в ключе `page`, ничего не помогло.

класс **Dfd_Layout_Builder**

```
    class Dfd_Layout_Builder {

        /** @var string Current page type. */
        private $page_type = '';

        /**
         * Constructor.
         *
         *
         * @since 1.0
         * @access private
         */
        function __construct($args) {
            $this->page_type = $this->get_page_type();

            $defaults = array(
                'loop' => 'loop',
                'page' => 'page',
                'class' => 'no-ttile',
            );

            $args = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);

            $this->build_layout($args['loop'], $args['page'], $args['class']);
        }

        /**
         * Get the layout width option value
         *
         * @since 1.0
         * @access public
         */
        function get_layout_width($page) {
            $layout_width = DfdMetaBoxSettings::get('dfd_layout_width');

            if(!$layout_width || empty($layout_width)) {
                global $dfd_native;
                $layout_width = isset($dfd_native[$page.'_layout_width']) ? $dfd_native[$page.'_layout_width'] : 'boxed';
            }

            return $layout_width;
        }

        /**
         * Check if custom header is enabled for current page
         *
         * @since 1.0
         * @access public
         */
        function get_stunning_header($page) {
            $stun_header_enabled = DfdMetaBoxSettings::get('dfd_stun_header');
            if(!$stun_header_enabled || empty($stun_header_enabled)) {
                global $dfd_native;
                $stun_header_enabled = isset($dfd_native[$page.'_stun_header']) ? $dfd_native[$page.'_stun_header'] : 'on';
            }

            if($stun_header_enabled == 'on') {
                get_template_part('templates/header/stunning-header');
            }
        }

        /**
         * Get the default page type to load default settings if no specific options were defined for current page from theme options or page metaboxes
         *
         * @since 1.0
         * @access public
         */
        function get_page_type() {
            $page_type = 'pages';

            if(is_404()) {
                $page_type = '404';
            }

            if(is_search()) {
                $page_type = 'search';
            }

            if(is_single()) {
                $page_type = 'single';
            }

            if(is_archive()) {
                $page_type = 'archive';
            }

            return $page_type;
        }

        /**
         * Generate sidebars configuration and 
         *
         * @since 1.0
         * @access public
         */
        function build_sidebar_config($loop, $page, $layout_width) {
            $item_sidebars = DfdMetaBoxSettings::get('dfd_sidebars_configuration');

            if(!$item_sidebars || empty($item_sidebars)) {
                global $dfd_native;
                $item_sidebars = isset($dfd_native[$page.'_sidebars_configuration']) ? $dfd_native[$page.'_sidebars_configuration'] : '';
                if(!class_exists('Dfd_Theme_Extensions')) {
                    $item_sidebars = '2c-r-fixed';
                }
            }

            $default = $this->page_type;

            $sidebars_count = 0;

            $this->top_dropdowns($page);

            if($item_sidebars && !empty($item_sidebars)) {
                switch($item_sidebars) {
                    case '2c-l-fixed':
                        $dfd_layout = 'sidebar-left';
                        $dfd_width = 'nine';
                        break;
                    case '2c-r-fixed':
                        $dfd_layout = 'sidebar-right';
                        $dfd_width = 'nine';
                        break;
                    case '3c-fixed':
                        $dfd_layout = 'sidebar-both';
                        $dfd_width = 'six';
                        break;
                    case '1col-fixed':
                    default:
                        $dfd_layout = 'no-sidebars';
                        $dfd_width = 'twelve';
                }
                $sidebars_count = (int) substr($item_sidebars, 0, 1) - 1;
                echo '<div class="blog-section ' . esc_attr($dfd_layout) . '">';
                echo '<section id="main-content" role="main" class="' . esc_attr($dfd_width) . ' columns">';
            } else {
                Dfd_Theme_Helpers::set_layout($default, true);
            }

            get_template_part('inc/loop/components/loop');
            new Dfd_Loop_Builder($loop, $page, $sidebars_count, $layout_width);

            if($page != 'product_single' && $page != 'shop') {
                comments_template();
            }

            if(!empty($item_sidebars) && $item_sidebars) {
                echo ' </section>';

                if (($item_sidebars == "2c-l-fixed") || ($item_sidebars == "3c-fixed")) {
                    get_template_part('templates/sidebar', 'left');
                    echo ' </div>';
                }
                if (($item_sidebars == "2c-r-fixed") || ($item_sidebars == "3c-fixed") || ($item_sidebars == "3c-r-fixed") ) {
                    get_template_part('templates/sidebar', 'right');
                }
                echo '</div>';
            } else {
                Dfd_Theme_Helpers::set_layout($default, false);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Generate layout and insert sidebars config
         *
         * @since 1.0
         * @access public
         */
        function build_layout($loop, $page, $class) {
            $layout_width = $data_atts = '';

            $page_type = $this->page_type;

            $class .= ' '.$page_type;

            if($page_type == 'pages' || $page_type == 'single' || $page_type == 'archive' || $page_type == '404') {
                $layout_width .= $this->get_layout_width($page);
            }

            $this->get_stunning_header($page);

            $vc_content_position = DfdMetaBoxSettings::compared($page.'_vc_content_position', '');

            $lazy_load_offset = DfdMetaBoxSettings::get('reduce_lazy_load_offset', '');

            if($lazy_load_offset && $lazy_load_offset == 'on') {
                $data_atts .= 'data-lazy-load-offset="1"';
            }

            echo '<section id="layout" class="'.esc_attr($class).'" '.$data_atts.'>';

                if($vc_content_position == 'top') {
                    $this->add_composer_content($page);
                }

                echo '<div class="row '.esc_attr($layout_width).'">';

                    $this->build_sidebar_config($loop, $page, $layout_width);

                echo '</div>';

                if($vc_content_position != 'top') {
                    $this->add_composer_content($page);
                }

            echo '</section>';
        }

        /**
         * Generate Visual Composer content for pages where posts, portfolio or gallery content is displayed
         *
         * @since 1.0
         * @access public
         */
        function add_composer_content($page = 'page') {
            $avail_templates = array('post', 'portfolio', 'gallery');
            if(in_array($page, $avail_templates) && $this->page_type != 'search') {
                if(have_posts()) {
                    echo '<div class="dfd-content-wrap dfd-vc-content-wrap">';
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                        $content = get_the_content();
                        if(substr_count($content, 'post-password-form') == 0) {
                            the_content();
//                          Dfd_Theme_Helpers::dfd_link_pages();
                            echo Dfd_Theme_Helpers::dfd_pagination();
                        }
                        unset($content);
                    endwhile;
                    echo '</div>';
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Generate categories, tags and authors dropdown sorters
         *
         * @since 1.0
         * @access public
         */
        function top_dropdowns($page) {
            if(DfdMetaBoxSettings::compared($page.'_cat_tag', 'off') == 'on' && !is_single() && !is_search()) {
                get_template_part('templates/'.$page, 'top');
            }
        }
    }
```

**P.S.**

```
add_filter('template_include', 'my_template');
function my_template( $template ) {

// если это страница со слагом portfolio, используем файл шаблона page-portfolio.php
// используем условный тег is_page()


    if( is_page('portfolio') ){
        $files = array(
            'tmp-portfolio.php',
            'portfolio.php',
            'tmp-page.php',
            'tmp-blog.php',
        );
        if ( $new_template = locate_template( $files ) )
            return $new_template ;
    }

    return $template;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

подключите нужный вам шаблон страницы в function.php

// фильтр передает переменную $template - путь до файла шаблона.
// Изменяя этот путь мы изменяем файл шаблона.

```
add_filter('template_include', 'my_template');
function my_template( $template ) {

// если это страница со слагом portfolio, используем файл шаблона page-portfolio.php
// используем условный тег is_page()


if( is_page('portfolio') ){
        if ( $new_template = locate_template( array( 'page-portfolio.php' ) ) )
            return $new_template ;
    }

# шаблон для группы рубрик
// этот пример будет использовать файл из папки темы tpl_special-cats.php, 
// как шаблон для рубрик с ID 9, названием "Без рубрики" и слагом "php"


if( is_category( array( 9, 'Без рубрики', 'php') ) ){
        return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/tpl_special-cats.php';
    }

# шаблон для записи по ID
// файл шаблона расположен в папке плагина /my-plugin/site-template.php


global $post;
    if( $post->ID == 12 ){
        return wp_normalize_path( WP_PLUGIN_DIR ) . '/my-plugin/site-template.php';
    }

# шаблон для страниц произвольного типа "book"
// предполагается, что файл шаблона book-tpl.php лежит в папке темы


global $post;
    if( $post->post_type == 'book' ){
        return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/book-tpl.php';
    }

    return $template;

}
```

Comment: добавил в вопрос код, который добавил в файл functions.php, но ничего не поменялось. Что можно ещё придумать?

Comment: решил проблему, дело в том, что была подключена дочерняя тема, и нужно было закинуть нужный шаблон в дочернюю тему

Comment: нет, всё-равно загружается архивный шаблон. Как-то некорректно работает данная тема. Дочернюю тему отключил, в результате хоть и выбран нужный шаблон в странице портфолио, загружается архивный шаблон. я так и не понял, почему перестал работать нужный шаблон

Comment: это много чего может быть, надо смотреть и ковырять

Comment: по пробуйте вынести сам контент из шаблона в отдельный файл